# Cannot connect to guest OS from host OS

Tags: port, tcp, opensuse, vmware-player

I have installed `OpenSUSE` on `VMWare player` as guest OS and my host OS is `Windows XP`. What I want to achieve is to send message from my host (i.e XP), say on port 7000 and receive it on a specific port on my guest, i.e. `OpenSUSE`, say on port 10000. I have a software using which I can send any message on a specified port. (That software uses `TCP`.)

I am pretty sure that I am not the first person on earth who is facing this scenario. But I am pretty new with this `VMWare player` and even `OpenSUSE`. Can anyone guide me with this?

**EDIT 1:**

**Output of `ifconfig` on OpenSUSE:**

```
Directory: /root
Tue May 24 14:58:18 EDT 2011
linux-gyuz:~ # ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:B9:F4:AF  
          inet addr:192.168.206.128  Bcast:192.168.206.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:feb9:f4af/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4621 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:903 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:6379045 (6.0 Mb)  TX bytes:75021 (73.2 Kb)
          Interrupt:19 Base address:0x2000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:72 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:72 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:4960 (4.8 Kb)  TX bytes:4960 (4.8 Kb)

linux-gyuz:~ #
```

**EDIT 2:** 
**Output of ipconfig /all on `XP`:**

Windows IP Configuration

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

```
    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : mycomp.com
    IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 205.142.113.181
    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.254.0
    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 205.142.112.1
```

C:\Documents and Settings\user>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

```
        Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : R8PPAV7
        Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : mycomp.com
        Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Peer-Peer
        IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
        WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
        DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : mycomp.com
                                            mycomp.com

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : mycomp.com
        Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82567LF Gigabit Network Con
nection
        Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-24-7E-DC-A4-A0
        Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
        Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 205.142.113.181
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.254.0
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 205.142.112.1
        DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 205.142.112.212
        DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 205.142.112.89
                                            205.142.112.103
        Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 205.142.112.89
        Secondary WINS Server . . . . . . : 205.142.112.103
        Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, May 24, 2011 1:03:31 PM
        Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, May 24, 2011 9:03:31 PM
```

Answer (score 4):

Aside from making sure you have the right IP address, it is also important to make sure a firewall is not interfering. Firewalls may use a 'stealth' mode, where they drop packets instead of replying, which may result in the connection timed out message you mentioned receiving in a comment.

1. Disable all firewalls.
2. Test the connection, do whatever you need to do to get a working connection while firewalls are disabled.
3. Open the correct port.
4. Reenable the firewalls.
5. Test again. If it only works with firewalls disabled, you probably need to fiddle with the opened ports. For troubleshooting, it helps to enable the firewalls one at a time so you can rule out working configurations.

openSUSE and Windows XP both come with firewalls. For openSUSE, you can access the firewall settings under the YaST2 Control Center, under Security and Users. For Windows XP, there should be something under the program menu (I can't remember off the top of my head). There should be numerous guides available for configuring these firewalls, if you need them, through a quick Google search.

Security suites often include their own firewalls (e.g. Norton, McAfee, Trend Micro, etc.). They will also need to be disabled/opened.

Answer (score 0):

There are several networking modes available under VMware Player, but all of them provide an IP for your guest OS  as well as networking connectivity with the host OS. So (just as if it were a separate physical machine) you just need to point to your guest's IP :)

In most flavours of linux (including OpenSuse) you can run `ifconfig` to see the IP address assigned to each interface.

Comment: just added output of `ifconfig` and `ipconfig`. They are even on different subnets. Will that be a problem?

Comment: Depends, which networking mode are you using? It's under VM Settings. Check the networking device.

Comment: If you're using `NAT` or `Host-only`, you're probably ok. If you're using `Bridged` then you have a problem.

Comment: it shows `NAT`

Comment: Should work then, just give her a go.

Answer (score 0):

I have VMware Workstation, which creates a new network on the host that the VM connects to, such as `192.168.206.x`. Via DHCP, the host might get `.1` and the guest `.128`, so you can send you message from the host to 192.168.206.128:10000 and have it get to the VM (which has to be listening on port 10000 of course).

VMware player should be the same if it creates networks, check the network connection properties on the guest or host to find the right IPs.

**EDIT:** Just saw your ipconfig output, try `ipconfig /all` or look in Control Panel -> Network Connections to see if there is "VMnet" adapter, with the same 192.168.206.x address.

Comment: added output for `ipconfig /all`. I can see two VMNet adapters in `Network connectionss`, their status is 'Connected, Firewalled'

Comment: Ok, one of those will be the right one, it doesnt matter which. Try pinging your guest OS IP `192.168.206.128`. If it works then you are in business.

Comment: @Spectre: `Request timed out.` :( I have also updated the question, (output of the `ipconfig /all` command, please have a look.)

Comment: @Bhushan: check to see that the VMware driver is bound. Control Panel->Network Connections->Local Area Connection->Properties, then make sure the boxes beside VMware are checked

Comment: @Code Bling: over there, box in front of `VMWare Bridge Protocol` is checked. Apart from that, I don't see any entry having `VMWare` in it.

Comment: @Bhushan hm..curious. At this point, it may be worth rephrasing your question to something like "Can't connect with VMware guest". You will probably get more views/answers